# Linux: write failed to update file after 2-3 days of long run

Tags: c, linux

I am writing some records to 100 file in regular interval of 1 and 2 seconds using Linux write system call.
 
file opened using:

```
LogFile = open(fileBuff, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | N_IRUSR | N_IWUSR | N_IXUSR);
```

When I read logs from the file in between some logs are missing.

Assuming my value starts from 1 and keep increasing so when I read it
`880, 881, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0, 887`
missing records '0' is sometimes more also.

1. I tried using fsync to flush the date to file,
2. Added proper semaphore locks and release
3. Instead of opening and closing the file each time, I tried keeping all descriptor globally and opening the files once, closing only when the application terminates

This is not the actual code, but this is exactly what I am doing.
saveRecordToFile is called from the read_queue.
in the Queue Maximum count size is 3000.

```
void saveRecordToFile(int fid, int writeindex, char *buff)
{
         int  LogFile = fid, Curpos = 0;

         semaCapture(&LogSema);
         lseek(LogFile,0,SEEK_SET);
         if((num_bytes = write(LogFile,&(writeindex),sizeof(long))) != -1)
         {
            if((num_bytes = write(LogFile,&(read_index),sizeof(long)) == -1))
            {
                LogMessage(LOG_ERROR, "Log read index Write failed, read_index:%d, num_bytes:%d, reason:%s \n",
                        read_index, num_bytes, strerror(errno));
            }
         }
         Curpos = (((writeindex) * sizeof(LogRecord)) + (2* sizeof(long)) + sizeof(PropertiesToSave));
         lseek(LogFile,Curpos,SEEK_SET);
         if((num_bytes = write(LogFile,bp,sizeof(LogRecord))) == -1)
         {
                LogMessage(LOG_ERROR, "LogRecord writing failed, num_bytes:%d, reson:%s\n",
                    num_bytes, strerror(errno));
         }
        LogFile = -1;
        semaRelease(&LogSema);
}
```

What measures can be taken care to avoid missing writes?

Comment: You're `seek`ing outside the lock

Comment: `LogFile = open(fileBuff, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | N_IRUSR | N_IWUSR | N_IXUSR);`?!?!?  Are you really bitwise-or'ing the open flags (`O_CREAT | O_RDWR`) with the mode bits `_IRUSR | N_IWUSR | N_IXUSR` and not passing an actual `mode` argument?

Comment: @Mat, Thanks for pointing out, I edited the code, But in code, I have taken care that part.

Comment: [`lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) also takes an `off_t` as the `offset` argument, not `int`.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, opening the file same way, Is that will create probem, I am not quite sure about that.

Comment: Of course passing incorrect arguments to `open()` can result in problems accessing the file.  Especially if the permissions bits your bitwise-or into the open flags happens to set something like the `O_TRUNC` or `O_APPEND` flag bit.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html

Comment: Let me try with using proper open flags and off_t..

open(fileBuff,   O_CREAT | O_RDWR,     N_IRUSR | N_IWUSR | N_IXUSR); 

This is correct.?

Comment: What is `N_IRUSR` etc? Shouldn't it be `S_IRUSR` etc? You have to pass an additional argument with the mode bits. `open(fileBuff, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR)`. I suggest to check that the return code of `write` or `read` is the number of bytes you expect, not only check for the error return of `-1`.

Comment: I take it that the `sema*` functions correspond to the "semaphore lock and release" you describe, but their details are unclear.  That you supposed that they might be useful in the first place suggests that multiple threads or multiple processes may be manipulating the file at the same time, and in that case, flaws in the locking scheme could *easily* cause problems such as you describe.  Please clarify by updating the question to present a [mcve].

Comment: The 1st call to `write()` misses any error logging.